# Argument expansion with format command

Tags: tcl

I came across a scenario, where I need to use the argument expansion with `format` command. With Tcl8.5, I am using `{*}` and it works like charm.

But, with Tcl8.4, i have tried `eval`. But, no luck.

```
% set x "This is stackoverflow"
This is stackoverflow
% format "%10s %5s %20s" {*}$x
      This    is        stackoverflow
% eval format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
   %5s
% eval list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
format %10s %5s %20s This is stackoverflow
% eval [list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x]
not enough arguments for all format specifiers
% eval format "%10s %5s %20s" [list $x]
       %5s
% eval format "%10s %5s %20s" [concat $x]
       %5s
```

What is my mistake here ?

Comment: You are aware that 8.4 is not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [eval and double substitution](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1017) part of the article.

The correct way would be:

```
eval "format {%10s %5s %20s} $x"
```

Here `eval` cannot concatenate any argument, so what gets to the interpreter is the substituted form: `format {%10s %5s %20s} This is stackoverflow`. You could of course use `eval "format \"%10s %5s %20s\" $x"` but I prefer avoiding escaping things with backslash when possible.

---

```
eval format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
```

Is wrong because eval first concatenates the strings together, so you end up with:

```
eval format %10s %5s %20s $x
```

Which is like saying `format %10s %5s %20s $x` and which is why you get what you got)

---

```
eval list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
```

Becomes:

```
eval list format %10s %5s %20s $x
```

Which is like saying `list format %10s %5s %20s $x` and nothing getting `format` to actually do something.

---

```
eval [list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x]
```

Is in the right direction, but `$x` is not getting expanded so you are doing `format "%10s %5s %20s" $x`.

---

The others only put `$x` into a deeper list or doesn't change anything in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The 8.4 idiom was to use `linsert` to create the command to be eval'ed

```
set x "This is stackoverflow"
set args [split $x]
set cmd [linsert $args 0 format "%10s %5s %20s"]
set formatted [eval $cmd]
```

or, nested in one line

```
set formatted [eval [linsert [split $x] 0 format "%10s %5s %20s"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Glenn.. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the way to write the invocation of a concat-and-evaluate command such as `eval` isn't clear, it often helps to replace the command with `concat` to see what is about to be evaluated, e.g. `concat format "%10s %5s %20s" $x` instead of `eval format "%10s %5s %20s" $x`.

These forms flatten the formatting string, making the second format specifier the first value argument (the first two are equivalent, `$x` being a flat list and thus the same as `[concat $x`]):

```
concat format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
# -> format %10s %5s %20s This is stackoverflow
concat format "%10s %5s %20s" [concat $x]
# -> format %10s %5s %20s This is stackoverflow
concat format "%10s %5s %20s" [list $x]
# -> format %10s %5s %20s {This is stackoverflow}
```

This form also inserts a list command that doesn't belong there:

```
concat list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x
# -> list format %10s %5s %20s This is stackoverflow
```

This form preserves the list structure of the formatting string, but unfortunately also preserves the list structure of `$x`:

```
concat [list format "%10s %5s %20s" $x]
# -> format {%10s %5s %20s} {This is stackoverflow}
```

These two forms do the right thing: they preserve the formatting string but flatten the argument list:

```
concat "format {%10s %5s %20s} $x"
# -> format {%10s %5s %20s} This is stackoverflow
concat [list format {%10s %5s %20s}] $x
# -> format {%10s %5s %20s} This is stackoverflow
```

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm)